# Jquery submit via post, but how to get the content of My DIVs

Tags: jquery

I have many div Elements (with Soccer Players on it)

I want to implement a submit Button and Send all
The Players from my field to my MySQL DB.

How could I get the values (IDs, and other attributes of the clicked elements which where clicked before)

Here is a fiddle, how the field looks like 
https://jsfiddle.net/qcvcga8k/47/

Structure is simple

```
<div Id="123">
Content
</div>
```

Thanks for any help ;)

Greetings

Comment: why dont you use a form, and post it ?

Comment: Because I have now only DIV elements and not (hidden) input fields ;)

Comment: Do you know how to pass parameters in a url ?

Comment: Yes with get parameters, but i made only experiences with forms not with blank HTML DIV elements

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/   
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );

Comment: Thanks for your help but how could I add the informations of all relevant div boxes in one post request... that's my problem..:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that I truly understant you, but if you want to get content of couple of divs selecting them via id attribute and then post it with ajax request, you can use this code:

```
var ids = ['123', '234', '345', '545', ...];
$('#yourSubmitButton').on('click', function(){

    var postData = {};
    ids.each(function(i, oneId){

        postData[oneId] = $('#' + oneId).html(); 
        // you can either use:
        // $('#' + oneId)[0].innerHTML or
        // document.getElementById(oneId).innerHTML   
    }); 

    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'url.that.will.process.the.data',
        data: postData,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);    
        } ,
        error: function(err){
            consolg.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```